# Edit form with two select controls to be filtered when first launched

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I have an edit form that includes two Select controls.

Both of them are populated from a remote data-base.

The first one shows states of a country, and the second one should show cities from the state selected at the first select control.

If I change the state at the first control, the second control is filtered and allows only to select cities from the selected state.

This situation is already done and works fine. Every time I change the state at the first control, the second control changes and show only the cities from the selected state.

My problem is that it is an "edit" form, and the state and city shown are the current values from the record.

If I want to change the city, the second control shows all cities from the database and not only the cities from the state value from the first control.

I don't know how to filter the second control when the form is first loaded, it shows first the current city value, but the control allows to select every other city, not only the cities from the current state value.

This is my code:

First control, State:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comunidad_enclave" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comunidad Autónoma</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="comunidad_enclave" onChange="getCities(this.value)">
          <?php 
do {  
?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_RSComunidades['id_comunidad']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_RSComunidades['id_comunidad'], htmlentities($row_Recordset1['comunidad_enclave'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_RSComunidades['nombre_comunidad']?></option>
          <?php
} while ($row_RSComunidades = mysql_fetch_assoc($RSComunidades));
?>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Second control, City:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="provincia_enclave" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Provincia</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="provincia_enclave" id="cities-list">
          <?php 
do {  
?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_RSProvincias['id_provincia']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_RSProvincias['id_provincia'], htmlentities($row_Recordset1['provincia_enclave'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_RSProvincias['nombre_provincia']?></option>
          <?php
} while ($row_RSProvincias = mysql_fetch_assoc($RSProvincias));
?>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
```

JavaScript that calls a PHP file to refresh the second control:

```
<script>
function getCities(val) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_contacts_po.php",
    data:'client_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#cities-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: maybe firing select event of state select on dom load will resolve your issue.. like $( document ).ready(function(){$("#comunidad_enclave").trigger('change'); });

Comment: Thanks @MuratCemYALIN, would you mind to explain your proposal in an answer. I don't understand the part: .trigger('change')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i were you i would have simply change my query on generating edit form to limit the city list on selected state but if you don't want to or don't know how to do that you can simply trigger the change function of your state select to make the filter of your city select when the document loaded... here is the js code for that...

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#comunidad_enclave").trigger('change'); //this triggers change event of comunidad_enclave select so that it will fire getCities function
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, but the current value for the second control is removed now. How could that value be kept and allow the second control to show only the cities from the first control current state value?

Comment: you can get that value before trigger change and after that you can reset that value...

Comment: Thanks, I have change the query for the second control and not included your JS proposal, you were right...